# How can i change text size in an android spinner?

Tags: android, text, view, size, spinner

Hi i have an android spinner populated from and array that i want to increase the text size of when it actually pops up. See at the moment it looks like this when it expands:

[image]

Which on an actual device is impractically small and doesn't look very good. I've tried changing the spinner xml properties But it doesn't seem to make a difference at all.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/frequencyspinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    >
```

**So how should i be altering the size/ centre of gravity for spinner choices?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html) that shows you how to set the layouts of the different rows.  What you'll need to do is create an array adapter that uses a custom view layout for the different rows.  The example is pretty good and I'm sure there are others.  Ask more if you have questions.